How to use go:embed to read from configs
I encountered a problem while writing a Go project. I try to follow standard project layout in which all .json files are in configs (or config) directory.
The problem itself is that I don’t understand the best way to write this .json file using go:embed (I use it on the advice of my teacher). He advised me not to do things like os.Open("../../configs/example.json") because it only works if the .json is nearby. But he didn’t show me how, in this case, without adding ../../ to the path, you can get to this .json file using embed. All processing in internal.
How can this be done in internal without breaking the project structure without moving .json from configs?
Inside internal I have package jsonproc, in which I tried to do something like:
//go:embed configs/*
//go:embed example.json
var config []byte

It didn't work out that way. Everything works if .json is placed next to this Go file in jsonproc. That way I can just write:
//go:embed example.json
var config []byte

But it's incorrect

where are you running go build and where does that standard expect you to be running go build?  Anyway, I wouldn't worry about that standard.  Sounds like you're doing course work.  Keep it as simple as possible, don't worry about a standard that's built for big enterprise projects.

It’s not even a standard for “big enterprise projects”, it’s a self-proclaimed standard which was asked to not claim itself as such by the community.

The embedded file needs to be colocated with the go file. In the following quick example main.go and hello.txt are in the same directory:
    package main
    
    import (
        _ "embed"
        "fmt"
    )
    
    //go:embed hello.txt
    var helloContent []byte
    
    func main() {
        fmt.Println(string(helloContent))
    }

